# Gimbal beacon not working in android

Tags: beacon, gimbal

I have a gimbal beacon. It is registered correctly in Gimbal Manager. I tested it with an iPhone. It works fine. But, android does not detect it at all. I tried it sample app, in my app but no chance. I have two android devices, I tried on those. Both don't work.

I am sure, package name is correct
I am sure, api key is correct
I am sure, startMonitoring is started

Is there any body can run Gimbal beacon with android devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Android are you running. 
Beacons are only supported from 4.4.3 onwards. 
But support for 4.4.x must be enabled manually in Gimbal Manager.
Check this section of the devguide
https://docs.gimbal.com/android/v2/devguide.html#add_app

Comment: it is 4.4.2 and 4.4.4. both dont work. but, I think you are mistaken. there are some features are supported 4.4.3 and onwards. but, gimbal itself supports, api 14. at least they claim they support. https://docs.gimbal.com/android/v2/devguide.html#confirm_your_environment

Comment: PlaceManager will work on api 14 onwards BUT 'beacons' will only work on 4.4.3 onwards. BLE support on Android 4.4.3 and 4.4.4 is terrible and that is why Gimbal makes you specifically enable support for these in Gimbal Manager. (see the link in my original post).